# remember checkbox value if its checked array name in a form php

Tags: php, arrays

lets say we have this:

```
echo '<form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width:auto">
              <tr>
                <td><label for="array">ARRAY_NAME</label></td>        
                <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="1" /> option1<br />
                 <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="2" /> option2
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="array2">ARRAY_NAME2</label></td>        
                <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="array2[]" value="1" /> option1<br />
                 <input type="checkbox" name="array2[]" value="2" /> option2
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="array3">ARRAY_NAME3</label></td>        
                <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="array3[]" value="1" /> option1<br />
                 <input type="checkbox" name="array3[]" value="2" /> option2
                </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>';
```

I tried to implement this code: `<?php echo (isset($_POST['array1[0]']) && $_POST['array1[0]'] == 1) ? "checked='checked'" : "" ?>`

but it didn't work! It only works if you have `name="array1"` and `name="array2"`. this way I'm thinking I can save multiple data in a parent array saved! Like this `form[array1[],array2[],array3[]]`.

Can someone give me a solution because I'm stuck! Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: imagine that sometimes you want both 2 values to be checked!

Comment: that's how you have to get the array from POST: `$array2= $_POST['array2']`, then get elements: `$array2[0]...` but **NOTE THAT** the array will have elements only for checked checkboxes, i.e you may have 10 checkbox tags, only 2nd 4th and last one are checked, so `array2` will have only 3 items, not 10, it will be little tricky to use the array to updated checked-status of your checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the values incorrectly.

You can access a array posted like this:

```
echo $_POST['array1'][0];
```

[php.net/$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) See the first comment.

Comment: thank you!! it was driving me crazy the syntact!!! it works!!!!! thank you again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you put square brackets in the name of form control, PHP will inflate that set of elements with similar names into an array.

You need to access:

```
$_POST['array1'][0]
```

**not**

```
$_POST['array1[0]'] // This is incorrect
```

(You also need to match the actual name of your control: Your HTML has `array`, `array2` and `array3` but not `array1`)